# monkeyrunner script - starting an activity that requires a permission

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

in a monkeyrunner script while launching an activity, is there a way to mimic yourself having a certain permission that the starting activity requires?

I am using "device.startActivity(component='com.package/.MyActivity)" but the activity MyActivity requires a permission, and hence device.startActivity fails.  Is there a way to give this permission to the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I had this problem, I solved it by creating a very small application(with the correct permissions in the manifest) that I pushed to the phone. All the application did was re-send intents sent to it, but to a different destination. My application also had a gui for triggering events manually, but that's optional.

Answer (score 0):

You can add permissions in AndroidManifest.xml file.

I don't know what monkeyRunner script is, and do we talk about the same permissions here, but in Android, all permissions you want to give to the app, you go to Manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

Running an activity through monkeyrunner is not exactly different than running it manually. So, when it asks for permission, you can verify it right after installation by sending an extra command like:

```
device.press('KEYCODE_ENTER', MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP)
```

or

```
device.press('KEYCODE_BUTTON_SELECT', MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP)
```

You can also get your application have system privilages by pushing it into a special folder with these commands:

```
>adb remount    
>adb push your\local\apk\path.apk system/priv-app
>adb shell stop
>adb shell start
```

Hope it works for you...